# Accessing Custom Permission from Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, permission-sets, custom-permission

I'm trying to check the User assigned Custom Permission from a Managed Package. The Custom Permission and the Permission Set are **not** part of the package, but in the subscribers Org.

Currently I'm trying to use the `FeatureManagement.checkPermission()`, but seems that the package can't access to the Custom Permission record.
The call inside the package returns `False`, when instead made from out of package (execute anonymous) the return value is `True`.

To be clearer, an example of code I'm running:

```
//execute anonymous
System.debug(NS.MyClass.customPermissionMethod('myCustomPermission')); //return false
System.debug(FeatureManagement.checkPermission('myCustomPermission')); //return true


//Managed Package Class    
global class MyClass {
    global static boolean customPermissionMethod(value) {
        return FeatureManagement.checkPermission(value);
    }
}
```

I have not found anything on the documentation that spoke of this specific case, has it ever happened to you?

Comment: I think that sounds right Andrea, because FeatureManagement seems to be built to check Custom Permission owned by a given Managed Package: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_manage_features.htm

Comment: Thanks Jeferson! It will be the case, however, there is no reference to the package in the "FeatureManagement Class" documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm#!). The methods performed outside the package work without particular constraints

Comment: Yes, you are correct as well Andrea, I think it might be worth to open a case then.

Comment: Yes, we'll contact the SF Support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce support told us that this is an error in the documentation, which they will correct.
The "checkPermission" method inside a managed package will only be able to verify the custom permissions of the package itself.
To get around this, you need to implement the "workaround" solution with 2 queries.

I don't fully agree with this choice/answer, but that's it.